# "Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null"

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Thanks for reading my post
I get this error on my code : "Class extends value # is not a constructor or null"
Here is my code, I'm trying to export/import classes.

monster.js :

```
const miniMonster = require("./minimonster.js");

class monster {
  constructor(options = { name }, health) {
    this.options = options;
    this.health = 100;
    this.heal = () => {
      return (this.health += 10);
    };
  }
}

let bigMonster = new monster("Godzilla");
console.log(bigMonster);

console.log(bigMonster.heal());

let mini = new miniMonster("Demon");
console.log(mini);
console.log(mini.heal());

module.exports = monster;
```

minimonster.js :

```
const monster = require("./monster.js");

class miniMonster extends monster {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.health = 50;
    this.heal = () => {
      return (this.health += 5);
    };
  }
}

let miniM = new miniMonster("Jon");
console.log(miniM);

module.exports = miniMonster;
```

Thank you for any help given,

Have a good day

Comment: Can you please console the contents of monster.

Comment: I would suggest to refactor your code to get rid of circular dependencies because it can get messy. You might add a third class that would manage those two.

Comment: aren't these 2 files including each other and depending on that? One class is probably not defined at one point

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I see at least one issue with your requires.

- `monster.js` first line is `const miniMonster = require("./minimonster.js");`
- `minimonster.js` first line is `const monster = require("./monster.js");`

This is a problem, you can not have both files evaluate at the same time.
I would not require `minimonster` from `monster.js`

This may fix your issue.

Answer (score 18):

When I get this error message it is because I have done my `module.exports` wrong.
eg.

**publicclass.js**

```
class PublicClass {
.....
}

module.exports.PublicClass = PublicClass;
```

instead of

```
module.exports = PublicClass;
```

Comment: Didn't even think about looking at the exports. This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I owe you a beer buddy

Comment: I put extended class in {} (within child class): `const { ParentClass} = require("./ParentClass");`

Answer (score 7):

For me, I had introduced a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Correct Code:

```
//Export from monster.js (but don't import minimonster.js)
class monster {
.....
}
let bigMonster = new monster("Godzilla");
module.exports = monster;

//Import in minimonster.js
const monster = require("./monster.js");
class miniMonster extends monster {
.....
}
let miniM = new miniMonster("Jon");
module.exports = miniMonster;
```

A circular dependency happens when module A depends on something in module B and module B depends on something in module A. This means to compile module A you must first compile module B, but you can't do that as B requires A to be already compiled.

So to avoid circular dependency we should not import a module (minimonster.js) that is exporting  a module (monster.js) in that same module (monster.js).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I put extended class inside of {}.

```
const { ParentClass } = require("./ParentClass");

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {    
}

module.exports = { ChildClass };
```

And:

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor() {}
}

module.exports = { ParentClass };
```

Answer (score -7):

I used as per below line.

```
import Base from "./base
```

and its working fine now